# Querying firebase database with a nested value

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Having some challenges querying my firebase database for an Android app I'm writing, I have the following structure;

```
Matches
 - Match_01
  - awayScore
  - awayTeam
  - date
  - gameID
  - homeScore
  - homeTeam
  - pitch
  - played
  - time
 - Match_02
  - awayScore
  - awayTeam
  - date
  - gameID
  - homeScore
  - homeTeam
  - pitch
  - played
  - time
```

I want to be able to query by using the gameID field, the problem I'm having is how to reference the gameID without explicitly setting a child("Match_01"), as I have Match_02, Match_03, etc... below is the code I'm playing with (which doesn't work, but gives you an idea of what I want to achieve). GetArgument is a value I'm passing into my fragment;

```
    DatabaseReference ref = database.child("Matches");
    Query gameQuery = ref.child().child("gameID").equalTo(getArgument);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it can be done like this:

```
 DatabaseReference ref = database.child("Matches");
Query gameQuery = ref.orderByChild("gameID").equalTo(getArgument);
```

when you use `orderByChild()` you do not have to specify the direct child under `Matches`